# rosjava - Compiling error

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

i have been trying to install rosjava by following documentation found on
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android.

in step 3 when asked to compile "rosmake android_app_chooser" i received an error. i downgraded like the next step suggests but i receive the following error.

```
 maven-install:
  [artifact:install] [INFO] Installing /home/user/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.roscpp-0.0.0.jar to /home/user/.m2/repository/org/ros/org.ros.rosjava.roscpp/0.0.0/org.ros.rosjava.roscpp-0.0.0.jar
  [artifact:install] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
  [artifact:install]  Diagnosis:
  [artifact:install] 
  [artifact:install] Error installing artifact 'org.ros:org.ros.rosjava.roscpp:jar': Error installing artifact's metadata: Error installing metadata: Error copying POM to the local repository.
  [artifact:install] Failed to copy full contents from /home/user/.ros/rosjava/maven/roscpp-pom.xml to /home/user/.m2/repository/org/ros/org.ros.rosjava.roscpp/0.0.0/org.ros.rosjava.roscpp-0.0.0.pom
  
  BUILD FAILED
  /home/user/.ros/rosjava/maven/maven-dependencies-roscpp.xml:20: Error installing artifact 'org.ros:org.ros.rosjava.roscpp:jar': Error installing artifact's metadata: Error installing metadata: Error copying POM to the local repository.


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package android_gingerbread written to: 10.4 sec ]                                                [ 2 Active 59/63 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /home/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111213-153002/android_gingerbread/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< android_gingerbread [FAIL] [ 10.38 seconds ]                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package android_gingerbread. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< actionlib_java [PASS] [ 23.76 seconds ]
```

How do i fix this error??

-thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12318/rosjava---compiling-error/) by [Jake_62](https://answers.ros.org/users/1504/jake_62/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible that you're experiencing this known issue: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=63

I suggest trying the described workaround.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0